# Change the character set in oracle 12c database

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, oracle12c

I need to change character set from **EE8ISO8859P2** to **EE8MSWIN1250**. 
I have read a lot of guides, but I have not found a solution. How can I make this conversion? I need a complete instruction.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to change it to UTF-8, i.e. `AL32UTF8` following the [Database Migration Assistant for Unicode Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm) or [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011).

As sandman also suggested, do **not** run `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...`
It is de-supported since Oracle 10g

[Database SQL Reference 10g Release 1: ALTER DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1004.htm#sthref2671):

> You can no longer change the database character set or the national
>   character set using the ALTER DATABASE statement. Please refer to
>   Oracle Database Globalization Support Guide for information on
>   database character set migration.

Comment: I need EE8MSWIN1250, not AL32UTF8.

Comment: Follow the Character Set Migration guide - **Changing the Database Character Set of an Existing Database**, it should cover any conversion.

Comment: Why do you like to convert to EE8MSWIN1250? Nowadays there is really no reason for any other character set (unless your DB is running in east Asia).

Comment: The database was created 20 years ago and the program that uses it is recommended EE8MSWIN1250 encoding. I do not know why someone chose such encoding when creating a database, despite the clear program guidelines. Now in several situations this causes problems and therefore I have to change the encoding to EE8MSWIN1250.

Comment: The person who recommended to use EE8MSWIN1250 has no clue about character sets and their proper usage.20 years ago this was still an issue, today it should be no problem anymore.

Comment: We also had to change our character set from US7ASCII to a single-byte MSWIN charset, as converting to unicode was estimate at 5 days (!) and there is no chance we will get that downtime for production.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be complicated with csscan etc. but nowadays you download a GUI tool called Oracle Database Migration Assistant and follow the instructions.  It's a lot easier if your character sets are single-byte (I'm assuming) as then you won't have lossy conversion of some data, for example a multi-byte character set like UTF8.

You will require downtime though and it might take hours to do, depending on the size of the data found by the DMU tool.  You can NOT change the character set by simply doing an 'alter database' as some people might suggest.

Comment: Why running alter database character set <code> and restarting wont have affect?

Comment: The GUI tool Oracle Database Migration Assistant is only for Unicode. There is no option for EE8MSWIN1250.

Comment: As long as it's in V$NLS_VALID_VALUES then there is no problem converting from source to target

Comment: Moudiz because that won't cater for data that needs to be converted.